Why not $\sf ZFC+[V=HOD]$?
Why not $\sf ZFC+[V=HOD]$ as the standard set theory?
It implies the existence of a definable global choice and well-order, and it is compatible with all large cardinal axioms extending $\sf ZFC$, so per maximality standpoint we are not losing anything, and more we are gaining a stronger notion of choice and more theorization and expressibility. Also, $\sf V=HOD$ is equivalent to saying that the parameter free definable sets forms an elementary substructure of the universe of sets, so it is saying that whatever is done by sets can be done by using parameter free definable sets. It's only among the latter ones that concrete sets can thrive, and accordingly are of the most convincing kind of sets intuitively speaking, so seeing that all work done in set theory can be done using them is a very strong feature to hold to, intuitively speaking. If the exposition of $\sf V=HOD$ is seen as being complex, it can be expressed metatheoretically in a simple manner by adding to $\sf ZFC$ an $\omega$-rule of definability that is:
$\textbf{Definability: }$ if $\phi_1,\phi_2, \phi_3,...$ are all $\sf FOL(=,\in)$ formulas in which only symbol "$y$" occurs free, and "$y$" never occur bound, and that doesn't use the symbol "$x$", and $\psi$ is a formula in which only symbol "$x$" occurs free, and "$x$" never occur bound; then:
$\underline {[i=1,2,3,...; \\ \forall x \, (x=\{y \mid \phi_i\} \to \psi)]} \\ \forall x: \psi$
In English: if a parameter free formula holds for all parameter free definable sets, then it holds for all sets.
This was proved by Hamkins to be equivalent over $\sf ZFC$ to the set theoretic axiom $\sf V=HOD$
So, it meets all intuitive and technical qualifications for it to be there!?

Strength is not the sole thing which makes something a desireable foundational theory. First and foremost it should be considered "natural" by the bulk of the community, and I highly doubt any form of V=HOD is gonna fly by that requirement.

Axioms of foundations are supposed to be clearly true. Not a formal gimmick.

@EmilJeřábek, there is nothing called 'clearly true', this is a mistake! But, you can say reasonably motivated of being true. And I think V=HOD is!

@Wojowu, EmilJeřábek I didn't appeal to strength neither to formal gimmickry. What is "natural" depends many times on the details of how it is motivated. I think it is intuitive for the role it assigns to explicit sets, and those are the most concrete of sets at intuitive level. It brings set theory very close to intuition. So, I see it is reasonably motivated of being true both intuitively and technically.

Clear truth is an important as noted by Emil, but it is also worth recognizing that the common use of ZFC is to some extent an accident of history. Replacement is much stronger than the vast majority of mathematicians need,  and if a slightly weaker version of it had been used in ZFC  or it had been removed completely from their axiomatization, you might be asking the same question about Replacement.

@JoshuaZ Not sure I agree with your remark, since of coruse replacement was absent from Zermelo's original theory, but this was seen as something to be addressed, and this is how we got ZFC.

@JoshuaZ, I'd disagree with you about that. Foundation, Choice, Powerset, and Replacement, and even Separation, actually even Extensionality, all have been contested, and up till today there is no unanimous consensus on their truth. Their canonization process was not immediate. But, they are there. They are all simply written, do have a natural appeal, technically flawless, and very useful to understanding sets. These are agreeable aspects. And perhaps that's the main reason for their being in the main list of axioms about sets. But, I think that V=HOD shares most of the same virtues.

I disagree with "parameter free definable sets ... are the most concrete of sets." The set ${n\in\omega:2^{\aleph_n}=\aleph_{n+1}}$ is parameter free definable, but I wouldn't call it concrete. We don't know, even for a single $n$, whether it's in this set.

@JoelDavidHamkins That's an excellent point and completely refutes my claim.

@Andreas Blass, Yes! Nice! I won't call it concrete too, but it can become concrete with additional axioms, so it is a kind of potentially concrete. I'd say that parameter free definability is a prerequisite for concreteness. I'll suitably edit. Thanks!

What does it mean to be a "standard" theory?
By any account, the theory ZFC + V=HOD already is one of the "standard" theories. The axiom V=HOD is intensely studied by set theorists; it appears as a hypothesis in innumerable theorems; it is seen as expressing a certain regularity phenomenon for the universe of sets; it is true in the constructible universe and all the canonical inner models of large cardinals; it is forceable by class forcing over any model of ZFC; it is a central concern in the model theory of set theory, in light of the fact that many theorems holding of models of PA in the arithmetic realm generalize to models of ZFC+V=HOD in the set-theoretic realm; and it is seen as saturated with philosophical significance.
We are already working out the nature of this theory and its relation with all manner of set theoretic ideas. What else would one want for this theory?
I see that you refer to "the" standard theory, but if this is meant to suggest that somehow everyone would agree to work only in that theory, then of course there is no standard theory in this sense.
The closest thing would be ZFC, of course, but even so, people routinely work in theories other than ZFC. Whole parts of the subject investigate failures of the axiom of choice, and in certain parts of the subject one routinely works in (often not completely specified) large-cardinal extensions of ZFC, or with determinacy assumptions, and so forth. Certainly it is not true that there is unanimous agreement to work exclusively in ZFC set theory.
Meanwhile, there are certain reasons not to take V=HOD as expressing a fundamental truth of set theory. In my multiverse paper, I explain how our understanding of HOD proceeds mainly by analyzing it in outer models where V=HOD fails:

We understand the coquettish nature
of HOD, for example, by observing it to embrace an entire
forcing extension, where sets have been made definable,
before relaxing again in a subsequent extension, where they
are no longer definable.

In other words, the axiom V=HOD is not robust with respect to inner and outer models—it is not always preserved by forcing; it's negation is not preserved by forcing. These features can be seen as a mark of fragility, perhaps a mark against it as a fundamental principle.

By standard axiomatic set theory I mean the one that set theorists are expected to mention in any chapter they'd write on introducing axiomatic set theory, it is the most accepted set of axioms about sets. I see ZFC having that status, but I see that ZFC+ V=HOD is ought to be considered also as such. There can be no unanimous consensus about any of the axioms of set theory even the most innocents ones like Extensionality. But, from your answer here, I'm even more motivated to consider ZFC+V=HOD to be in the canonical set of axioms about sets.

@ZuhairAl-Johar It is a purely sociological question which set theory is "standard" in your sense of the term. We now live in a "post-standards" world, and there's little hope of dislodging ZFC from its conventional role (well, there may be some hope of adding infinitely many inaccessibles, since that is assumed by the most popular proof assistants). Of course, people continue to argue about axioms, such as V=L. But the result of such arguments is predictable.

@TimothyChow, I do concede that there is some sociological aspect to coining of standards. But, I do also think that it is not merely so. There must be some reasonably presented argument for motivating such development, and by reasonable I mean not merely being sociological, but something that touches the very nature of the manipulated concept. It is this true core touch that I'm into here. So, it is YES, there is a human factor into it, and NO, it is not only that human factor, and it is the NO that is most important!

@ZuhairAl-Johar Certainly, back when ZF was first proposed, "reasonably presented arguments" were indeed given. But you seem to implicitly assume that an open dialogue is continuing until this very day, with the choice of foundation remaining "up for grabs" to the most persuasive debater. While a minority of people still think that way, it's a sociological fact that the majority regards the choice of foundation as largely a matter of convenience and convention. The attitude is, if you have a favorite axiom, by all means investigate it, but don't expect us to switch foundations.

Similarly, I think you exaggerate the extent to which the other axioms, such as extensionality, are in flux. Some standard weakenings of ZFC are widely studied, such as ZF, ZF_fin, KP, ZF-power, ZFC-power, as well as alternatives such as ZFA, ZFU, ZFCU, etc., and these can all be considered "standard" theories. Dropping extensionality, although studied, is at best a curiosity.

@TimothyChow, When matters mature up to a great degree, it would be harder to push further, matters just freeze at certain stage, that's nature I suppose, you see that obviously in Religion, traditions, etc.. But, what you said is not really all together correct. Suppose we proved Replacement inconsistent, the standard would change! Suppose you found something that makes much of a difference, then the standard must add it. It will no doubt slowly grow, but it ought to grow, there is no need to keep it fixed at all, as if it is a divine edict.

@JoelDavidHamkins, I think Non-standard arithmetic is widely studied, should we consider an alternative standard? Perhaps some would think so. I personally think that it ought not to. The standard is the simplest, most natural, most appealing grasps of a concept, that is thought to be what is true about it. Non-standards are always interesting, but not as much as the standard. You may view the non-standard as standard and then look from its perspective to see the standard non-standard, this way you undermine what is standard and just consider it a kind of appealing bias. I don't think so!

@ZuhairAl-Johar Certainly, if an inconsistency is found, that would force a re-evaluation. But I disagree that an axiom that makes a big difference "must" be added. There are many known set-theoretic axioms that make a big difference, but they have not been added to the foundation. We have just made a note of the consequences of these axioms, and moved on. This has happened many times over. Hugh Woodin has made the case for many axioms, but the larger mathematical community remains unmoved. If anything, the trend nowadays is to weaken the foundation, not strengthen it.
